# ActiveRecord group by on a join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Really been struggling trying to get a group by to work when I have to join to another table.  I can get the group by to work when I don't join, but when I want to group by a column on the other table I start having problems.

```
Tables:
Book
id, category_id

Category
id, name

ActiveRecord schema:

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end
```

I am trying to get a group by on a count of categories.  I.E. I want to know how many books are in each category.

I have tried numerous things, here is the latest,

```
books = Book.joins(:category).where(:select => 'count(books.id), Category.name', :group => 'Category.name')
```

I am looking to get something back like

```
[{:name => fiction, :count => 12}, {:name => non-fiction, :count => 4}]
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just after the count of books in each category, the association methods you get from the `has_many` association may be enough (check out the [Association Basics guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_many-association-reference)). You can get the number of books that belong to a particular category using

```
@category.books.size
```

If you wanted to build the array you described, you could build it yourself with something like:

```
array = Categories.all.map { |cat| { name: cat.name, count: cat.books.size } }
```

As an extra point, if you're likely to be looking up the number of books in a category frequently, you may also want to consider using a counter cache so getting the count of books in a category doesn't require an additional trip to the database. To do that, you'd need to make the following change in your books model:

```
# books.rb
belongs_to :category, counter_cache: true
```

And create a migration to add and initialize the column to be used by the counter cache:

```
class AddBooksCountToCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :categories, :books_count, :integer, default: 0, null: false

    Category.all.each do |cat|
      Category.reset_counters(cat.id, :books)
    end
  end
end
```

---

**EDIT**: After some experimentation, the following should give you close to what you want:

```
counts = Category.joins(:books).count(group: 'categories.name')
```

That will return a hash with the category name as keys and the counts as values. You could use `.map { |k, v| { name: k, count: v } }` to then get it to exactly the format you specified in your question.

I would keep an eye on something like that though -- once you have a large enough number of books, the join could slow things down somewhat. Using `counter_cache` will always be the most performant, and for a large enough number of books eager loading with two separate queries may also give you better performance (which was the reason eager loading using `includes` changed from using a joins to multiple queries in Rails 2.1).

Comment: isn't that making multiple trips to the DB (at least one for each category, maybe one more for the count)?

Comment: To build the array? It depends on the code you use to pull the records from the DB. If you use `counter_cache`, you get everything in one hit (`@categories = Category.all`); without it, you could get everything in (probably) two calls by eager loading books (`@categories = Category.includes(:books).all`), although loading all the books could get pretty massive depending on the size of the table. With no eager loading and no `counter_cache`, `@categories = Category.all` would give you N+1 hits.

Comment: Even without the books count cache I should be able to do a count with a group by to get it in one query right?  Which is what I was trying to do.

Comment: A'ight, worked out how to do it the way you want, and updated my answer. I would still recomment `counter_cache` as the best way to implement this though, it will give you the best performance.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:
`Category.joins(:books).group("categories.id").count`
It should return an array of key/value pairs, where the key represents the category id, and the value represents the count of books associated with that category.